# DATEADD uses wrong region format

Tags: sql, sql-server, dateadd, regional-settings

For some reason specifically only the DATEADD function is using the region format yyyy-dd-mm instead of the normal yyyy-mm-dd for everything else. I don't understand why this would happen I'm not even American.

For me `DATEADD(day, 7, '2021-09-01')` as a column returns a datetime of 2021-01-16 00:00:00.000 not the expected 2021-09-08 00:00:00.000.

Would anyone know if this a known issue in SSMS with the `DATEADD` function? I am using SQL Server Management Studio v17.9.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a problem with SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), which is just an IDE *for* SQL Server (telling us you're using SSMS 17 is like telling us you're using Office 2016 when asked what version of Windows you're using), nor SQL Server, but your literal strings. Firstly, what you should *really* being using `DATEADD` against is a strongly typed date and time value; then you *always* get the value you expect.

As for your literal strings, however, the format `yyyy-MM-dd` is *not* unambiguous as the way it is interpreted differs when using the (old) `datetime` and `smalldatetime` datatypes. `DATEADD` (and `DATEDIFF`) will implicitly convert a string based data type to a `datetime`; and such conversion is interpreted according to your language settings (meaning your format is ambiguous).

The fix is to therefore use an unambiguous format. For SQL server these are `yyyyMMdd` and `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn`. So `DATEADD(day, 7, '20210901')` will return 08 September 2021 *regardless* of your language settings.

Comment: Thanks using '20210901' works as expected as opposed to the '2021-09-01'. I'm not sure I fully comprehend what your saying but I guess I have some reading to do on "strongly typed date and time" and datetime data types. Really appreciate the explanation regardless.

Comment: [Date and time types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-and-time-types?view=sql-server-ver15) @SandGrug .

Comment: Interesting, I thought yyyy-MM-dd *was* an unambiguous format...